# How to put session data in SetUp() - Django testing

Tags: django, session, testing, installation

I am setting session data in SetUp() in Django testing but it raises an error not found. What's missing here?

```
def setUp(self):
    session = self.client.session
    session['email'] = 'hi@test.com'
    session.save()

def test_valid_data(self):
    form = CreationForm(data=self.valid_data)
    u1 = form.save(email=session['email'])
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set session to your instance property:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.session = self.client.session
    self.session['email'] = 'hi@test.com'
    self.session.save()

def test_valid_data(self):
    form = CreationForm(data=self.valid_data)
    u1 = form.save(email=self.session['email'])
```